# If anaconda has a package and it is not in pip, how do I install it?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I want to install [`gudhi`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gudhi/files) packages.

It seems that the package only says that it can be installed only with anaconda. But I want to install it with `pip` , not anaconda.

When I checked the package, I found a zip file called tar.bz2, which I tried to install using it, but I can not figure out what to do.
And I do not know if this is the right way.

So I would like to seek advice.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `pip install gudhi` available.
If you don't want to go with conda, you will have to follow the [installation guide](https://gudhi.inria.fr/python/latest/installation.html).

If `make cython` works, you can then `[sudo] python[3] setup.py install` to install it on your system.

[EDIT]
A [gudhi pip package](https://pypi.org/project/gudhi/) is now available.